# VS Code using wrong Google Cloud account when running project locally with Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

I am using VS Code with Google's Cloud Code plugin. I was using my personal email address which is tied to a personal instance of Google Cloud. I was given a sandbox instance of Google Cloud for a project at work. Although I have logged into Google Cloud with my work email address, whenever I try to run my project with Cloud Code in a Kubernetes development session, an error is logged about permissions referencing my personal account. I believe this is because VS Code is somehow stuck with my personal email address.

I tried logging out of all accounts from the VS Code command pallet to no avail.

How do I resolve this?

Here is the error in GCP logging. I was clued in that it was my personal account's email address because of the logging entry's label: `principal_email: my_personal@email.address`. Naturally, my personal email address is not part of my work's GCP instance, therefore the permissions issue.

```js
{
insertId: "redacted"
logName: "projects/redacted/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
authenticationInfo: {1}
authorizationInfo: [2]
metadata: {1}
methodName: "storage.buckets.create"
requestMetadata: {4}
resourceLocation: {1}
resourceName: "projects/_/buckets/redacted"
serviceName: "storage.googleapis.com"
status: {1}}
receiveTimestamp: "2022-09-09T12:07:41.184289826Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2022-09-09T12:07:40.135804318Z"
}
```

I apologize if this is the wrong stack exchange for this question. If so, please direct me to the right one.

Comment: After removing any personal data, would you be willing to include the error message for `an error is logged about permissions referencing my personal account`

Comment: I'm not sure what will work. My initial "turn it off and on again" instinct wonders if you can uninstall the Cloud Code extension and reinstall it? I don't know how well the Cloud Code extension handles multiple accounts/switching accounts.

Comment: Good idea.. I don't know why that didn't cross my mind!

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall of the plugin didn't work. Neither did uninstalling/reinstalling VS Code - I'm going to have to figure out where VS Code stores its cache and blow that away as well, I think.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it's store in the gcloud CLI somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247920/discussion-between-dshiz-and-luke-schlangen).

Comment: I've not used the plugin but its documentation suggests that it uses [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install#authentication_with) (which makes sense) to authenticate to Google APIs. Can you try `gcloud auth login your_work@email.com` and then [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) to force the ADC to be recreated using the corporate address. Then restart VS Code.

Comment: Deleting the plugin and VS Code likely did not work because -- often -- configuration is not deleted with the app and so, reinstalling, reuses the old config. In this case, I think the config is obtained from ADC which, on Linux, is a file `${HOME}/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` (and created by the `gcloud auth application-default login` command).

Comment: It was definitely some kind of corruption of the plugin. I uninstalled/reinstalled it, then signed out and back in via the plugin's Help and Feedback menu (which coincidentally was missing before reinstall), and the error cleared.

Comment: Since you were able to solve the problem in the comments, please share the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According with @Dshiz the solution was:**

> It was definitely some kind of corruption of the plugin. I
> uninstalled/reinstalled it, then signed out and back in via the
> plugin's Help and Feedback menu (which coincidentally was missing
> before reinstall), and the error cleared.